# In cmdb_rel_ci table I want to retrieve all the unique parent.sys_class_name with count for Type Depends on::Used by

Tags: servicenow

In the cmdb_rel_ci table, I want to retrieve the value and total count of all the unique parent.sys_class_name values for Type(cmdb_rel_type) "Depends on::Used by".

I was trying to use with GlideAggregate, but classname is showing empty. 
Can anyone offer some advice?

Comment: Next time, include your code if you want anyone to take the time to help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use GlideAggregate on the cmdb_ci table, not cmdb_rel_ci. The rel table has no sys_class_name if I recall.
You could also try dot-walking to it using GlideRecord, or using a Join query.

I don't know what "for type Depends on::Used by" means. Pretty sure it doesn't mean anything.

Please take the time to explain your questions **clearly** and include your **code** next time if you're expecting anyone to take time out of their day to help you.

Comment: No, you're not more clear. 
Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested already, use Glideaggregate (more info [here](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/api_doc?v=jakarta&id=c_GlideAggregateScopedAPI))

Try this as an example:

```
var ga = new GlideAggregate('cmdb_rel_ci');
ga.addQuery('type.name', 'STARTSWITH', 'Depends on::Used by');
ga.addAggregate('COUNT', 'parent');
ga.query();
while (ga.next()) {
  var parent = ga.parent.getDisplayValue();
  var parentCount = ga.getAggregate('COUNT', 'parent');
  gs.info('CI ' + parent + ' has ' + parentCount + ' relationships with type Depends on::Used by');
}
```